# rails CanCan: Fetching records with accessible_by and additional 'where' clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, record, cancan

I am currently using [the accessible_by method](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records) of CanCan to fetch only relevant records of a model, which the logged-in user can access. So far, so good.

But how can I add to such a `Foobar.accessible_by(current_ability)` an additional 'where' clause?

I tried `Foobar.accessible_by(current_ability).where(...)`, but that gives me an Exception: `SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're including a model that share the same attribute. If you want to use this attribute and keep the include you need to specify the model, e.g.:

```
Foo.include(:bar).where(:bar => { :name => 'xyz' })
```

This should be done in either your ability or in the .where(...), but that depends on the content of that ability and where.

Comment: You might wanna put the `include .. where` statement into a `scope` as you can adapt from this [CanCan wiki article](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities).